# Track the closing of client application launched through Java Web Start

Tags: java, jnlp

A main class is invoked through a JNLP file using Java Web Start from a client machine.
I want to update server DB table based on successful launch and closing of the application in client machine.

Is there any way to track such events using Java Web Start itself ?

Answer (score 0):

It is application specific. What is the criteria that the application has successfully started? The main did not throw exception? It is not enough: probably application throws 10 exceptions from other threads. So, you have to implement your own application dependent mechanism that understands that application started successfully. Then notify your server side either directly by opening JDBC connection (bad solution) or via web service that updates the DB (better solution)